# Powershell 'runspace' does not run from the Powershell console

Tags: powershell, runspace

I am trying to understand why this code will run in the Powershell ISE but not from the Powershell console

```
function close-window (){
    # close
    $hash.window.Dispatcher.Invoke("Normal",[action]{ $hash.window.close() })
    # clean up
    $powershell.EndInvoke($handle) | Out-Null
    $runspace.Close() | Out-Null
    $powershell.Dispose() | Out-Null
}

    $hash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
    $runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
    $runspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
    $Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
    $runspace.Open()
    $runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("hash",$hash)
    $Powershell = [PowerShell]::Create()
    $powershell.AddScript({ 
    $xaml = [xml]@"
        <Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="Window" Title="Splash Screen" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Width="499" Height="272" BorderBrush="#FF2AA0F1" ShowInTaskbar = "False" AllowsTransparency="True"
        ResizeMode = "NoResize" BorderThickness="1" >
    </Window>
"@

    $reader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml
    $hash.window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
    $hash.window.Add_MouseRightButtonUp({ $hash.window.close() })
    $hash.window.ShowDialog()
})

    $Powershell.Runspace = $runspace
    $handle = $Powershell.BeginInvoke()
```

Run it from the ISE and you get the expected result of a XAML window appearing.
Save the file and run it from the console and it fails silently 
Copy and paste it into the console and it fails silently.

It contains a single runspace with a synchronised hashtable
Because it is XAML, I start the runspace as a single threaded apartment.
When running from the console have tried MTA and STA

The aim is to use this piece of code as part of a splash screen.

Comment: I copied / pasted this into a PowerShell console window, and it shows me an empty WPF window, as expected.

Comment: what is your command line you are using to execute this code?

Comment: Thanks guys, your comments helped.
I played around with all options in the command line but could you get it to work, I suspected -mta and -sta to be the most the culprit, sorry I should have put the command line in, will next time.
Knowing that it worked OK for someone else pointed me in the right direction.
The script was missing any references to assembly names, I added this and it works OK now          

`Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase, System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script was missing references to any assembly names, not a problem in the ISE but required for the console.

```
 Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore, PresentationFramework
```

Comment: Hi - I am having the same problem, as you were having. But I cannot get it to work, even when loading the right assemblies. It just opens a PS window and the closes it again, without showing any GUI. Did you do anything else to get it to work?